# assign a single texture to atlas type uv-map?

Tags: uv

I have an environment model from a game and i was trying to assign the textures in Blender. In this example, there are hundreds of leafs on a wall and i have a single texture of a leaf, but the uv-map shows them all next to each other in varying sizes, like a texture atlas. Is it possible to assign the texture without re-unwrapping the mesh? I have to keep the original uv-map intact, to make it look exactly like in the game.

example:
[image]

Comment: It's not really clear why in-game model spends texture space like that but try baking - duplicate model where you unwrap all the leaves into maximum texture space, setup materials and bake textures to the original one

Comment: that might work in this case, but there are other architectural parts of the mesh that are far more complicated. unwrapping everything in a duplicate would take weeks.

Comment: It wouldn't regarding the leaves as all one needs to do is to enter Edit mode and reset UV map from U menu. Architectural details might require another approach and they might be another problem. With setup above likely there's no other way to apply texture to each individual uv island without any changes to original UV map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make another UV map, unwrap leaves individually to a leaf image and then bake it to the atlas texture using the original UV map, like this:

**Whole procedure in one gif**

[image]

**Invidividual steps:**

1. Create new image for the atlas texture by going to UV/Image and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
   [image]
2. Create new UV map

   [image]
3. Create a material with a leaf texture

   [image]
4. Select All <kbd>A</kbd>, change image in UV/Image editor to the leaf image and then Unwrap <kbd>U</kbd> > Reset - this sets whole UV 
   space for each leaf so you can apply your leaf texture to all of them individually. Adjust UV to your needs.

   [image]
5. Switch back to original UV map and click on the camera icon of the UV map with individual leaves (so we will bake from this UV map)

   [image]
6. Navigate to *Render* > *Bake*, hit *Bake*

   [image]
7. Your leaves are now baked into the atlas texture

   [image]